# Dragleave event doesn't fire consistently when draging over multiple targets in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop, draggable

I've built an `HTML5` based solution that let's me drag and drop items around to change their order in a list, and it works great in Chrome, IE, and *mostly* in Firefox. There's just one scenario I've identified where it falls down:

In Firefox, when an item is dragged at high speed across one drop target into another, `dragleave` doesn't always fire. `dragenter` and `dragover` events are fired as expected for the item that's passed over, but (sometimes, when you do it just so) `dragleave` is not.

I've got no *simple* example of this one at this point, given how entangled it is with what I'm working on, but you should be able to reproduce it on the [fully complicated version](http://omnichron.net/external/sandbox/ffdrag/sheet_alt.html). The events log to console, for your ease of reference, and the relevant code starts around line 700 of the js file. Visually, you'll see the insertion indicators stick around when they shouldn't because the function that removes them never got called.

At this point I've more or less convinced myself that I'm not doing anything wrong, and that this is an issue with Firefox, but I figured I'd ask some experts. Anyone else run into this? Is there an existing bug for it I just couldn't find? Thoughts, suggestions, ideas, or what have you?

Edit: Added [a simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DashielN/EMRSa/) to demonstrate this.